# Javascript Lodash syntax error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

For some reason I can't seem to find where by syntax error would be in this Lodash function. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong here?

```
const classes = _.filter(state.classes, class => {
  return class.date === moment()
});
```

Here is the error I'm seeing (using React Native):
[image]

The particular position it is referring to (64:49) is after the `class` on the first line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`class` is a keyword](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-keywords). Keywords cannot be used as variable names. Use a different name for the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a different name for your function parameter, `class` is a reserved keyword :D